# Pass Anonymous Components Attribute as object

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade

I have a Blade Anonymous Component.

I want to pass an attribute to the components as object.

When I do this, the object converts to string

The component file:

```php
@props(['object'])

{{ $object }}
```

The component call:

```html
<x-component object="object variable" />
```

Comment: What do you see if you replace {{ $object }} with dd($object)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this, prepending a `:` before the attribute name. Example:

**welcome.blade.php**

```
@php 
  $customer = (object)['name' => 'Kenny'];
@endphp
<x-customer-component :customer="$customer"/>
                      ^
```

**customer-component.blade.php**

```html
<div>
  <p>Hey, my name is {{ $customer->name }}</p>
</div>
```